# How to get two random numbers from a list of lists?

Tags: python-2.7

When I tried to generate two random numbers from lists of list and the two random numbers should be from two different lists in a list, I got two elements from the same list in a lists of list.

Example:

```
list1 = [[1,2,],[3,4],[5,6]]
import random
random.choice(random.sample(l,2))
output = [5, 6]
```

and

```
for random.sample(random.choice(l),2)
output = [2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand what you asked for, but if you want a random element from list of lists,

```
>>> import random 
>>> from itertools import chain 
>>> list1 = [[1,2,],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> random.choice(list(chain.from_iterable(list1)))
4
>>> random.choice(list(chain.from_iterable(list1)))
3
>>> random.choice(list(chain.from_iterable(list1)))
1
```

What `chain.from_iterable(iterable)` does is, flatting the list of lists.

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(list1))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable